# animation of random number incrementation with jquery

Tags: jquery, animation

I have the following which animates the number without the randomness, but I want it to be random, how can I achieve this?

```
$({boatValue: 0}).animate({boatValue: 12 }, {
    duration: 1500,
    easing:'swing', // can be anything
    step: function() { // called on every step
        // Update the element's text with rounded-up value:
        $('#boat-count').text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.round(this.boatValue)));
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by random? You want the `12` value to be random, or something else...?

Comment: so that it randomly shows number until it reaches 12, eg. 1,18,78,28,48,39,24,19,39,12 @RoryMcCrossan